# Why are my screenshots only black?

Tags: screenshot, xna-4.0

could someone tell me why my screenshots are only black? I am still learning and couldnt find a clue why they are only black.

This is my Utility class

```
static class XNAUtilities
{
    private static RenderTarget2D ssTexture;
    private static KeyboardState currentState, previousState;
    private static int counter;

    public static void TakeScreenShot(GraphicsDevice device, Keys theKey)
    {
        // Take Screenshot
        currentState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (currentState.IsKeyDown(theKey) && previousState.IsKeyUp(theKey))
        {
            //device.SetRenderTarget(null);                                                         
            PresentationParameters pparameters = device.PresentationParameters;
            ssTexture = new RenderTarget2D(device, pparameters.BackBufferWidth, pparameters.BackBufferHeight, false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.None); //??
            FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"Screenshot" + "_" + counter + ".png", System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew);
            ssTexture.SaveAsPng(fileStream, pparameters.BackBufferWidth, pparameters.BackBufferHeight);

            counter++;
        }
        previousState = currentState;
    }
}
```

}

This is my Update and Draw from Game1.cs

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        myModelRotation += MathHelper.ToRadians(1f);

        // Take a Screenshot
        XNAUtilities.TakeScreenShot(GraphicsDevice, Keys.F8);

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[myModel.Bones.Count];
        myModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in myModel.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effects in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effects.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effects.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index]
                    * Matrix.CreateRotationY(myModelRotation)
                    * Matrix.CreateTranslation(myModelPosition);
                effects.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(200, 100, 400), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);

                effects.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45f),
                    GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio, 1, 5000);
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }


        smileySprite.DrawSprites(GraphicsDevice, spriteBatch, new Vector2(10,10), Color.White);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually rendering to your render target. So you're saving the blank target.

You need to wrap your scene drawing like so:

```
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(ssTexture);
// Render your scene here
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
// Now you can save your render target as a texture
```

Comment: i dont get it... sry. where i have to put this code in or with witch lines i have to change it.. i am confused right now...lol

Comment: @Dave: After you create the render target, and *before* you save it, you must *draw something to it*. In order to draw to a render target it must be set on the device (so your scene draws to the render target instead of the back buffer).

Comment: After you create the render target --> GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(ssTexture);

and before i save it -->>
ssTexture.SaveAsPng(fileStream, pparameters.BackBufferWidth, pparameters.BackBufferHeight);

you must draw something to it.
what i think i am doing it with this
-->ssTexture = new RenderTarget2D(device,pparameters.BackBufferWidth, pparameters.BackBufferHeight, false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.None);

or i am stupid??
i really dont get it.

Comment: i had only a XNA 3.1 tutor and figert all this of my own out, but i rally stuck. In 3.1 it was used ResolveTexture2D what is obsolite in 4.0..

Comment: You need to render your scene - as you do in your game's `Draw` function - to the render target (where I have put a comment instructing you to do so). None of the code you or I have posted so far does that. The line with `new` is what *creates* the empty render target. `SetRenderTarget` tells the graphics device to use it as the drawing surface. In XNA 4.0 a render target is also a texture - you don't need to resolve it, you can just call `SaveAsPng` on it.

Comment: it cant be that hard... good i hate it if you got only an older tutor and have to find the soloutions and stuck.. maybe my brain isnt working that good.. grrrrrr i will give it another try ..it have to be a way to get it rigth :-) but thx for your great help.. i know i am anoying

Comment: ok, i think i know what i should say as well... my code is in a seperate class... my code above is called from the update method in Game1 when i press f8. i try it first inside the game1 class.. maybe i will get the clou then...

Comment: I postetd both classes now. maybe it will help to understand what is wrong in my code and help me to sort it out.. I tried now 2 days to find awnsers. Google. forums.. I use Visual 2010 and XNA 4.0. Everything what i find is for XNA3.1 and that doesent work for 4.0 anymore.